# Rbenv and ruby build on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rbenv

I have install rbenv and ruby-build on Ubuntu DISTRIB_RELEASE 16.04 but anytime I start my terminal I get the message below on the terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to your profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="/home/godfred/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/home/godfred/.rbenv/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
local command
command="${1:-}"
if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
shift
fi
case "$command" in
rehash|shell)
eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;*)
command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
esac
}
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to your profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these configuration to your .bashrc file. Those will be load rbenv during terminal start.

```
if [ -d $HOME/.rbenv ]; then
    export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
    export PATH="$RBENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
    eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

Note: your rbenv installation path can be different. Check before set those to you .bashrc file.

Comment: Please tanvir002700 this is the path I already have in my bashrc file.   export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "(rbenv init .)"
eval "(rbenv init -)"
eval "(rbenv init .)"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

Comment: Did your .profile file set these configuration ? 
```
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
 . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```